# How to use USING clause for more than one Indexes

Tags: neo4j

I would like to use the following query for neo4j for indexing based on two indexes can this be done

```
MATCH (n:Movie)
USING INDEX n:Movie(released)
USING INDEX m:Movie(title)
where n.released = 2008 and m.title = "Speed Racer"
return n
```

The above syntax is incorrect. Can someone let me know the correct syntax.
Also how do i go about full text search using labels ?

Error

```
 m not defined (line 3, column 13)
"USING INDEX m:Movie(title)"
```

Comment: please send the output of `profile MATCH (n:Movie)
where n.released = 2008 and m.title = "Speed Racer"
return n;` executed in neo4j-shell

Comment: Aren't you mixing identifiers m and n??

Comment: No i just want to use two indexes in a where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MATCH (n:Movie)
USING INDEX n:Movie(released)
USING INDEX n:Movie(title)
where n.released = 2008 and n.title = "Speed Racer"
return n
```